# Horror short story anthology from early 80s with spider story

Tags: story-identification, books, short-stories, horror

I'm trying to track down a horror anthology book from the early 80s. I'm fairly sure it was called something like '50 tales of horror and suspense' and definitely had a cover painting consisting of a human skull with snakes wrapped around it.

The one story I remember, which I believe was the first one, was about a family in, I believe, Mexico, who move into an old house. The young boy explores the upstairs and discovers a large and somewhat threatening spider. Believing the spider is his friend, he continues to visit it, unknowingly endangering himself, until his father discovers the spider and kills it.

Kind of a long shot, I know, but maybe someone will remember this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe [*50 Great Horror Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1158866) edited by [John Canning](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?115342)? At least one edition had a skull-and-snakes cover,

[image: Cover of 50 Great Horror Stories]

and the [table of contents](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?407403) lists a story titled "A Date with a Spider" by [Vida Derry](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?127802) starting on p. 211. That story was previously published in *John Creasey Mystery Magazine* [v 2 # 2, October 1958] according to [The FictionMags Index](http://www.philsp.com/homeville/fmi/t/t3183.htm#A70053). All this is from browsing the web; I've never seen the story myself, so I don't know if it bears any resemblance to your description.

Comment: This is indeed the exact book! I don't know how my Google-fu failed me so badly; I searched many times but couldn't find it for some reason. Thanks!